# MS Access: if I put a button on multiple rows form, can I detect on which row the button was clicked

Tags: ms-access, vba

Since the button is unbound to any record, can I detect on which row the button was clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Clicking the button sets focus to record row the button is on. So code that references fields of that record would pull values from that record. Form must be in Continuous view for button to display.